# How do I patch mock multiple calls from os in python?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a method that does the following:

```
    import os

    ...

    if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        os.makedirs(dirpath)
```

I'm trying to mock the `makedirs` and `path.exists` but when I do this with `patch` the mocks conflict:

```
@patch('os.makedirs')
@patch('os.path.exists')
def test_foo(self, makedirs, exists):
    c = Config()
    c.foo()

    assert makedirs.called
    assert exists.called
```

If I disable either `makedirs` or `exists` they both work fine but have an issue when being used together.

I've also tried using `with patch('os.makedirs') as makedirs:` syntax which doesn't change anything.

Does anyone know why they are conflicting or what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mock `os.path.exists` as you do, it will return a mock, which always evaluates to `True` - so your code will never reach `os.makedirs`. To make this work, you have to provide a return value for the mock:

```py
@patch('os.makedirs')
@patch('os.path.exists', return_value=False)
def test_foo(self, exists, makedirs):
    c = Config()
    c.foo()

    makedirs.assert_called_once()
    exists.assert_called_once()
```

Note also that the order of the mocks was reverted in your code - the argument for the last patch decorator has to go first.

I have also replaced `assert xx.called` with `xx.assert_called_once()` - the `assert_called_...` methods of `Mock` provide more fine-grained possibilities for checks.